# Choosing One table among two tables on the basis of some attribute value in MVC3 and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

Suppose I have a base class Component and two derived classes ComponentA and ComponentB, something like below:

```
public class Component
{
   public int ComponentID {get; set;}
   public int ComponentType {get; set;}
   // some other statements ...
}
```

And then

```
public class ComponentA : Component
{
   // some statements ...
}

public class ComponentB : Component
{
   // some statements ...
}
```

Now, on the basis of the value of the COmponentType in class Component, How to switch to ComponentA or ComponentB and retrieve their related data.

This is one of the examples how to do this in edmx, but I want to know is there any way to do the same thing in Code First approach in EF. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-4-0-tph-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can found TPH (Table per Hierarchy) with code first [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `ComponentType` property and EF will automatically create a `Component` table with a `Discriminator` column that is used to discriminate (duh) between the subclasses.

If you need a specific column name and/or data type for the discriminator column you can override the defaults in the `OnModelCreating` event of your `DbContext`, either directly, or by an `EntityTypeConfiguration` e.g. by doing

```
Map(m => m.Requires("ComponentType").HasValue(1);
```

for each subtype. (`HasValue` with a different value each time, obviously).

You will create a property `DbSet<Component>` in the context. This returns all components, irrespective of type. If you only want `ComponentA`s do

```
context.Components.OfType<ComponentA>(). ...
```

Oh, and `Component` should be an abstract class.